Parse different schema
Need parsing approach to read a fixed length file efficiently
Sample File
A01DataHasBeenloaded
A02DataHasbeenParsedAndLoadedToMemory
A03CatIsInTheBag
A01....
A02....
A03....
and so on
The first group of A01,A02,A03 belongs to Record 1 and next group belongs to Record 2 and so on.One thing to note that the All lines staring with A01,A02 and A03 will have different schemas respectively.Currently the schema is as below
recordMarker: A

schema:
  - column_name: Name_1

    sequence: 'A01'

    startchar: 1

    length: 3

    value: 'A01'(optional)


  - column_name: Activity

    sequence: 'A01'

    startchar: 4

    length: 14



  - column_name: Name_2

    sequence: 'A02'

    startchar: 1

    length: 3

    value: 'A02'(optional key)


  - column_name: Progress

    sequence: 'A02'

    startchar: 4

    length: 16

  - column_name: Name_3

    sequence: 'A03'

    startchar: 4

    length: 37

    value: 'A03'(optional key)

  - column_name: Event

    sequence: 'A03'

    startchar: 4

    length: 37

Sequence A01 has Name_1,Activity columns
Sequence A02 has Name_2,Progress columns
Sequence A03 has Name_3,Event columns

The sequence key actually helps in mapping which columns belongs to which schema.

The record marker is the prefix to filter out the records starting with A


I need to map each of A01,A02,A03 in continuation of lines to Single record(pivoting those schema).Resultant dataframe will have Name_1,Activity,Name_2,Event,Name_3,Progress columns.Currently I am using monotonically_increasing_id which could be inefficient in case, one of the schema(suppose with sequence A03) belonging to same record may reside in different partition and rest of the two(A01 and A02) in another partition which could lead to inconsistencies in record.
Current logic is as below:
def _create_sequence_dataframes(self, raw_df: DataFrame) -> Dict[str, DataFrame]:
            sequence_dfs = {}
            for field in self.record_schema.schema:
                if field.sequence not in sequence_dfs:
                    sequence_df = raw_df.filter(
                        substring(col("value"), 1, len(self.record_marker) + 2)
                        == f"{self.record_marker}{field.sequence[-2:]}"
                    )
                    sequence_dfs[field.sequence] = sequence_df

                sequence_dfs[field.sequence] = sequence_dfs[field.sequence].withColumn(
                    field.column_name,
                    substring(col("value"), field.startchar, field.length),
                )

            for sequence, df in sequence_dfs.items():
                sequence_dfs[sequence] = df.drop("value")

            return sequence_dfs


def _join_sequence_dataframes(
    self, sequence_dfs: Dict[str, DataFrame]
) -> DataFrame:

        sequences = sorted(list(sequence_dfs.keys()))
        
        for seq in sequences:
                sequence_dfs[seq] = sequence_dfs[seq].withColumn(
                    "row_id", monotonically_increasing_id()
                )

        base_df = sequence_dfs[sequences[0]]
        for seq in sequences[1:]:
                base_df = base_df.join(sequence_dfs[seq], "row_id", "outer")

        result_df = base_df.drop("row_id")
        return result_df


def process_data(
    self, spark: SparkSession, file_path: str
) -> DataFrame:
    
    raw_df = spark.read.text(file_path)
    sequence_dfs = self._create_sequence_dataframes(raw_df)
    joined_df = self._join_sequence_dataframes(sequence_dfs)
    return joined_df

process_data is the main module which calls the other two.
Please suggest other approaches to parse the file efficiently

Try to pre-process the file outside of Spark. Due to its distributed nature it's difficult to keep the order of rows inside of Spark.
This bash script merges the three lines that belong together into one line. The idea is to replace the newline characters of lines starting with A01 or A02 with empty strings.
awk '{ORS = match($0,/^A0[1,2]/) ? "" : "\n"} 1' data.txt > preprocessed.txt

If data.txt was
A01Activity1_____
A02Progress1_______
A03Event1______________________________
A01Activity2_____
A02Progress2_______
A03Event2______________________________
A01Activity3_____
A02Progress3_______
A03Event3______________________________

preprocessed.txt would be
A01Activity1_____A02Progress1_______A03Event1______________________________
A01Activity2_____A02Progress2_______A03Event2______________________________
A01Activity3_____A02Progress3_______A03Event3______________________________

This file can now be handeled by Spark:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=spark.read.text('preprocessed.txt')

df.withColumn('Name_1', F.substring('value', 0, 3)) \
    .withColumn('Activity', F.substring('value', 4, 14)) \
    .withColumn('Name_2', F.substring('value', 18, 3)) \
    .withColumn('Progress', F.substring('value', 21, 16)) \
    .withColumn('Name_3', F.substring('value', 37,  3)) \
    .withColumn('Event', F.substring('value', 40 , 37)) \
    .show()

Output:
+--------------------+------+--------------+------+----------------+------+--------------------+
|               value|Name_1|      Activity|Name_2|        Progress|Name_3|               Event|
+--------------------+------+--------------+------+----------------+------+--------------------+
|A01Activity1_____...|   A01|Activity1_____|   A02|Progress1_______|   A03|Event1___________...|
|A01Activity2_____...|   A01|Activity2_____|   A02|Progress2_______|   A03|Event2___________...|
|A01Activity3_____...|   A01|Activity3_____|   A02|Progress3_______|   A03|Event3___________...|
+--------------------+------+--------------+------+----------------+------+--------------------+

